# How do I store old leads so they don't bother the current leads?

Tags: contacts, custom-fields

Is there a module like "leads" and "contacts" for un useful leads?

Comment: Without knowing more about how your information is structured, it's difficult to answer your question.  Can you please edit your question and tell us more about what you're tracking, how your presently storing the data, and how you'd like it to be?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Tags to denote Leads v Unleads.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tags, as Pete suggested.

However, CiviCRM does NOT have the built-in concept that some CRMs (notably Salesforce) that indicates "don't show this contact in search results by default".  I agree it would be a great feature but it's not there at the moment.

Comment: We have had a similar request recently to be able to 'Archive' contacts so that they don't show up in standard searches. Trash does this quite well so I wonder if a solution would be to go down that approach again for 'archived'

Comment: @petednz-fuzion I've hesitated to go down that road with folks because Deleted and Archived (or Leads, or non-donor contacts, or any of the other use cases I've seen) shouldn't be the same thing.  Of course, until someone steps up to do the work (or sponsor it), I think your answer makes sense.

Comment: in case my shorthand wasn't clear, i was thinking that Archived would work along same lines as Trash, ie column in Contact table to denote 'archived' and all searches would ignore results unless a 'search in archives' or 'also include archives' checkbox was ticked, much as "search in trash' works - but agree that until a sponsor comes along it will gather dust ;-)